# How to reference a required class in JSDoc that was required in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

In file `app.js`, I have the following

```
const pg = require('pg');
const Engine = require('./engine.js');
```

Then in `engine.js`, I have this:

```
class Engine {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {pg.Client} db - The pg client database object
     */
    constructor(db) {

    }
}

module.exports = Engine;
```

I would like to get JSDoc to recognize the type pg.Client from `app.js` but JSDoc is just labeling the type "any".